# Why does the postgres tx id not start at 1 for a newly created database?

Tags: postgresql

I am trying to understand the details of how postgres deals with transactions; I noticed that when the execute the following commands on psql I get a txid that is at 518526 instead of a low number like 0 or 1 which is what I expected would happen.

```
postgres=# CREATE DATABASE test;
CREATE DATABASE
postgres=# \connect test;
You are now connected to database "test" as user "postgres".
test=# begin;
BEGIN
test=# select txid_current();
 txid_current 
--------------
       518526
(1 row)
```

On a second psql console I type

```
postgres=# CREATE DATABASE test3;
CREATE DATABASE
postgres=# \connect test3
You are now connected to database "test3" as user "postgres".
test3=# begin;
BEGIN
test3=# select txid_current();
 txid_current 
--------------
       518528
(1 row)
```

So it looks like for all databases in the postgres server the next txid seems to be shared across all databases. Why does postgres use txid across databases not on a per database basis?

Comment: Why _should_ it? The transaction_id should be a non-decreasing sequence of numbers. Which it is, even when it is increased by transactions in other databases.

Comment: Although you can only *connect* to one database at a time, I think a large amount of Postgres's data is actually managed at the "cluster" level. For instance, native replication can only be done on a per-cluster level.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The transaction ID counter is global across the server. This is necessary partly because PostgreSQL has some global tables, like `pg_database`, `pg_role`, etc that are visible across all databases. To make these transactional we need a global transaction ID.

You shouldn't be using the transaction ID for anything except an identifier for a transaction. You can't even assume that a lower transaction ID is an older transaction, due to transaction ID wrap-around.

You can use `txid_current_snapshot` and `txid_visible_in_snapshot` (if you're on a new enough PostgreSQL) to reason about visibility. Surprisingly, I don't see a system function to compare two transaction IDs with respect to the current global xmin for transaction wrap-around.

Comment: Thanks very much, you answers are always excellent.  My goal for the question was simply to understand. I don't intend to use the xid for anything other than a tutorial to introduce devs on my team to how postgres manages transactions.