# What kind of key should be used to group multiple rows within the same database table?

Tags: postgresql, transactions

## Use case

I need to store texts assigned to some entity. It's important to note that I always only care about the most current texts that have been assigned to that entity. In case new texts are inserted, older ones might even be deleted. And that "might" is the problem, because I can't rely that really only the most current texts are available.

The only thing I'm unsure about how to design is the case that some INSERT can provide either 1 or N texts for some entity. In the latter case, I need to know which N texts belong to the most current INSERT done for one and the same entity. Additionally, inserting N instead of 1 text will be pretty rare.

I know that things could be implemented using two different tables: One calculating some main-ID and the other mapping individual texts with their own IDs to that main-ID. Because multiple texts should happen rarely and a one table design already provides columns which could easily be reused for grouping multiple texts together, I prefer using one only.

Additionally, I thought of which concept would make a good grouping key in general as well. I somewhat doubt that others really always implement the two table-approach only and therefore created this question to get a better understanding. Of course I simply might be wrong and everybody avoids such "hacks" at all costs. :-)

## Possible keys

### Transaction-local timestamp

Postgres supports the concept of a transaction-local timestamp using [current_timestamp](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-CURRENT). I need to have one of those to store when the texts have been stored anyway, so they might be used for grouping as well?

While there's in theory the probability of collisions, [timestamps have a resolution of 1 microsecond](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/datatype-datetime.html), which is in practice enough for my needs. Texts are uploaded by human users and it is very unlikely that multiple humans upload texts for the same entity at the same time at all.

That timestamp won't be used as a primary key of course, only to group multiple texts if necessary.

### Transaction-ID

Postgres supports [txid_current](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/functions-info.html#FUNCTIONS-TXID-SNAPSHOT) to get the ID of the current transaction, which should be ever increasing over the lifetime of the current installation. The good thing is that this value is always available and the app doesn't need to do anything on it's own. But things can easily break in case of restores, can't they? Can TXIDs e.g. occur again with the restored cluster?

People knowing things better than me write the following:

> Do not use the transaction ID for anything at the application level. It is an internal system level field. Whatever you are trying to do, it's likely that the transaction ID is not the right way to do it.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/32644144/2055163

> You shouldn't be using the transaction ID for anything except an identifier for a transaction. You can't even assume that a lower transaction ID is an older transaction, due to transaction ID wrap-around.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/20602796/2055163

Isn't my grouping a valid use case for wanting to know the ID of the current transaction?

### Custom sequence

Grouping simply needs a unique key per transaction, which can be achieved using a custom sequence for that purpose only. I don't see any downsides, its values consume less storage than e.g. UUIDs and can easily be queried.

### Reusing first unique ID

The table to store the texts contains a serial-column, so each inserted text gets an individual ID already. Therefore, the ID of the first inserted text could simply always be additionally reused as the group-key for all later added texts.

In case of only inserting one text, one should easily be able to use `currval` and doesn't even need to explicitly query the ID of the inserted row. In case of multiple texts this doesn't work anymore, though, because `currval` would provide updated IDs instead of the first one per transaction only. So some special handling would be necessary.

### APP-generated random UUID

Each request to store multiple texts could simply generate some UUID and group by that. The mainly used database Postgres even supports a [corresponding data type](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/datatype-uuid.html).

I mainly see too downsides with this: It feels really hacky already and consumes more space than necessary. OTOH, compared to the texts to store, the latter might simply be negligible.

Comment: Whatever implementation you choose is likely to be a matter of opinion. For my part why complicate a simple solution. You either need to store multiple texts or you don't. Since you do **every query** you write for this has to assume multiple, and jump through whatever hoops  you create. The simplest is just use 2 tables and write simple joins, otherwise you need to always write self-joins. Keep your solution as simple as possible. Consider additional texts be added after the initial insert. Either at this point or later modification? Do your alternatives support that?

Comment: @Belayer There won't be any modifications by design, only always new INSERTs with the new current state of interest for texts for some entity. Older available texts might be deleted at some point as well. I tried to make that more clear and thought that this might be an additional argument for a one table design.